# What is the best practice to insert a row after some consecutive rows in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below data in a table:

```
REGION,CATEGORY,SUBCATEGORY,ItemName,ItemViews,sales,ItemViewspercentage
CE,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Commands,5,4,125.00%
EA,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Commands,2,1,200.00%
SO,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Commands,2,1,200.00%
WE,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Commands,5,5,100.00%
CE,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Recognition Tips,2,2,100.00%
EA,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Recognition Tips,1,1,100.00%
SO,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Recognition Tips,3,2,150.00%
SW,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Recognition Tips,3,3,100.00%
WE,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Recognition Tips,3,3,100.00%
EA,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Setting Clock,3,1,300.00%
SO,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Setting Clock,1,1,100.00%
WE,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Setting Clock,3,1,300.00%
SW,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Setting Presets,2,1,200.00%
CE,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Sound Settings,1,1,100.00%
WE,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Sound Settings,1,1,100.00%
CE,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Vehicle Settings,1,1,100.00%
CE,KIA Drive Wise,Android Auto,Driver Attention Warning,4,3,133.33%
EA,KIA Drive Wise,Android Auto,Driver Attention Warning,2,3,66.67%
SO,KIA Drive Wise,Android Auto,Driver Attention Warning,4,3,133.33%
SW,KIA Drive Wise,Android Auto,Driver Attention Warning,1,1,100.00%
WE,KIA Drive Wise,Android Auto,Driver Attention Warning,5,5,100.00%
```

I want the above data to be like:

```
REGION,CATEGORY,SUBCATEGORY,ItemName,ItemViews,sales,ItemViewspercentage
CE,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Commands,5,4,125.00%
EA,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Commands,2,1,200.00%
SO,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Commands,2,1,200.00%
WE,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Commands,5,5,100.00%
Total,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Commands,14,11,78.57%
CE,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Recognition Tips,2,2,100.00%
EA,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Recognition Tips,1,1,100.00%
SO,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Recognition Tips,3,2,150.00%
SW,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Recognition Tips,3,3,100.00%
WE,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Recognition Tips,3,3,100.00%
Total,Infotainment,Safe Exit Assist,Voice Recognition Tips,12,11,109.09%
EA,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Setting Clock,3,1,300.00%
SO,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Setting Clock,1,1,100.00%
WE,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Setting Clock,3,1,300.00%
Total,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Setting Clock,7,3,233.33%
SW,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Setting Presets,2,1,200.00%
CE,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Sound Settings,1,1,100.00%
WE,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Sound Settings,1,1,100.00%
Total,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Sound Settings,2,2,100.00%
CE,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Vehicle Settings,1,1,100.00%
Total,Infotainment,Voice Recognition,Vehicle Settings,1,1,100.00%
CE,KIA Drive Wise,Android Auto,Driver Attention Warning,4,3,133.33%
EA,KIA Drive Wise,Android Auto,Driver Attention Warning,2,3,66.67%
SO,KIA Drive Wise,Android Auto,Driver Attention Warning,4,3,133.33%
SW,KIA Drive Wise,Android Auto,Driver Attention Warning,1,1,100.00%
WE,KIA Drive Wise,Android Auto,Driver Attention Warning,5,5,100.00%
Total,KIA Drive Wise,Android Auto,Driver Attention Warning,16,15,106.66%
```

I want to insert a row after some particular number of rows. Which loop in SQL server should I use to accomplish my work?

Comment: *"Which loop in SQL server should I use to accomplish my work?"* None of them; Looping is the *last* thing you should be doing in SQL. SQL is a set based language, and so you should be using set based solutions.

Comment: Also, are you *really* using SQL Server 2008? It's been *completely* unsupported for almost 3 years; it's long past time your sorted out your upgrade path.

Comment: It seems you are mistaking a RDBMS for a spreadsheet application - there is no such concept as inserting rows at a specific position. Are you actually trying to create a report with sub-totals? Those can simply be calculated.

Comment: `SELECT region, category, ... FROM theTable
union
SELECT 'total', category, ... SUM(item_views), SUM(sales), SUM(percentage) /* or AVG? */
GROUP BY category, subcategory, itemname` would return the data at least, you'd need to care for appropriate ordering yet...

Comment: Yes I want to create a report which will show me the total calculations for specific items.

Comment: As @Filburt suggests, tables don't have 2 "natural" order. You don't "insert" a row into the middle of your table, it's added to the end. if you want your data in a specific order, then you define that when you get the data from your table, by using an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Sounds like you need `GROUPING SETS` but it's unclear how to aggregate `ItemViewspercentage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this

```sql
SELECT
  REGION = CASE WHEN GROUPING(REGION) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE REGION END,
  CATEGORY,
  SUBCATEGORY,
  ItemName,
  ItemViews = SUM(ItemViews),
  sales = SUM(sales),
  ItemViewspercentage = FORMAT(SUM(ItemViews) * 1.0 / SUM(sales), 'P2')
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY, ItemName, REGION),
  (CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY, ItemName)
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=49dec53242208720cdf118120daf8138)